# C# Array index is out of range but index is zero

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

```
public int Laenge = 10;
public int Breite = 10;   
public Vector3[] new_Ver = new Vector3[300];
public Vector3[,] new_Ver_s = new Vector3[11,11];
public Vector2[] new_UV = new Vector2[300];
public Vector2[,] new_UV_s = new Vector2[11,11];


void Start () {
int n=0;
for(int l=0;l<=Laenge;l++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<=Breite;b++)
        {
            if(b>1 || l<Laenge)
            {
                if(b%2 ==1)
                {
                    Debug.Log(l);Debug.Log(b);Debug.Log(n+"f");
                    new_Ver[n]=new_Ver_s[l,b]; //this is the line where it says theres a bug.
                    new_UV[n]=new_UV_s[l,b];
                    n++;
                }     
            }
        }   
    }
```

It says:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range

but debug says all indizes are zero. Is it because the elements are empty? How can i easily put something in there? If i do the same thing with a twodimensional array, there is no problem.
I tried something and replaced new_Uv_s with an empty vector3 variable. It´s still the same error.´

Comment: You should use a debugger and step through your code to see at which point you get the exception. This will probably tell you what is wrong in your logic.

Comment: Check sizes of new_Ver_s, new_UV and new_UV_s arrays

Comment: sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doomed to crash because you increment **n** at each iteration, and you may have something like 50 iterations => at some point **n will exceed 29** the last index of the **new_Ver** array.

Why have you set its size to 30?

If you want some latitude use 100. :)

Comment: That is right i have to change it to 300. But it doesnt even do one loop.

Comment: Are you sure because your code seems correct? You should really use a debugger like the one provided with Visual Studio.

Comment: i put debug.logs everywhere for l b and n and its always zero and it only runs until to the point where i put the comment in the code. I thought it is maybe because the array is empty.

Comment: Do you have an idea what i can look for?

Comment: I've tested your code and it works perfectly, at least it does not crash and loop 54 times. What tool are you using: Visual, CSC, MonoDevelop...

Comment: I guess you mean **Unity3D** the engine and not **Unity** the DI framework? If so please update the tags of your post with *Unity3D* instead of *Unity*. So you have an issue elsewhere because as far as C# is concerned your code is good. :)